# Is the aggregation information in kubernetes dashboard available at the CLI? Or through an API?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I've seen in the Kubernetes dashboard the tracking of some information in the form of:

> X happened 14 times and the last occurence was at time T

Where is this data coming from?  Can I query for it using the `kubectl`?  Is there a K8s API for this information as well?  Or is the dashboard running some kind of aggregation internally?

Comment: show exact error

Answer (score 0):

> X happened 14 times and the last occurence was at time T
> That is OOB dashboard functionality and most probably you should dive deep into the code to answer this question.

The thing is of course dashboard relies on open data that you can collect on your own using `kubectl` - the only question is what exactly you wanna see as output. Using `kubectl` in spike with greps, sorts, seds, etc will give you the same information you just asked. Maybe you wanna create new question and specify your exact task?